# How to know location about partition in hive?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

If I write a hive sql like

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name ADD PARTITION (dt=20131023) LOCATION 'hdfs://path/to/tbl_name/dt=20131023;
```

How can I query this location about partition later? Because I found there is some data in  location but I can't query them, hive sql like

```
SELECT data FROM tbl_name where dt=20131023;
```

Comment: how can one list locations of all the partitions not just one?

Comment: @morpheus I use a for loop with  `show partitions table;` to show locations of all partitions. I don't find a one-line command to implement this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
show table extended like 'tbl_name' partition (dt='20131023');
```

> [Show Tables/Partitions Extended](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-ShowTables/PartitionsExtended)
>
> `SHOW TABLE EXTENDED` will list information for all tables matching the given regular expression. Users cannot use regular expression for table name if a partition specification is present. This command's output includes basic table information and file system information like `totalNumberFiles`, `totalFileSize`, `maxFileSize`, `minFileSize`, `lastAccessTime`, and `lastUpdateTime`. If partition is present, it will output the given partition's file system information instead of table's file system information.

Answer (score 57):

Do a describe on the partition instead of the full table.
This will show the linked location if it's an external table.

```
describe formatted tbl_name partition (dt='20131023')
```

Answer (score 16):

If you have multiple nested partitions, the syntax is:

```
describe formatted table_name partition (day=123,hour=2);
```

Comment: For multi-level partitions the full spec needs to be provided as shown here.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know the location of files you're reading, use

```
SELECT INPUT__FILE__NAME, BLOCK__OFFSET__INSIDE__FILE FROM <table> WHERE <part_name> = '<part_key>'
```

Then you get

```
hdfs:///user/hive/warehouse/<db>/<table>/<part_name>=<part_key>/000000_0.snappy, 0
hdfs:///user/hive/warehouse/<db>/<table>/<part_name>=<part_key>/000000_1.snappy, 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the format of the command I use to get the exact HDFS location of a specific partition in a specific table:

```
show table extended like flight_context_fused_record partition(date_key='20181013', partition_id='P-DUK2nESsv', custom_partition_1='ZMP');
```

In the command above, the partition spec consists of three separate fields.  Your example may have more or less.

See results below.  Notice the "location:" field shows the HDFS folder location.

```
hive (nva_test)> show table extended like flight_context_fused_record partition(date_key='20181013', partition_id='P-DUK2nESsv', custom_partition_1='ZMP');
OK
tableName:flight_context_fused_record
owner:nva-prod
location:hdfs://hdp1-ha/tmp/vfisher/cms-context-acquisition-2019-06-13/FlightContextFusedRecord/2018/10/13/ZMP/P-DUK2nESsv
inputformat:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat
outputformat:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat
columns:struct columns { string primary_key, string facility, string position, i32 dalr_channel, i64 start_time_unix_millis, i64 end_time_unix_millis, string foreign_key_to_audio_segment, struct<on_frequency_flight_list:list<struct<acid:string,ac_type:string>>,transfer_list:list<struct<primary_key:string,acid:string,data_id:string,ac_type:string,from_facility:string,from_position:string,transition_time:i64,transition_time_start:i64,transtition_time_end:i64,to_facility:string,to_position:string,source:string,source_info:string,source_time:i64,confidence:double,confidence_description:string,uuid:string>>,source_list:list<string>,domain:string,domains:list<string>> flight_context}
partitioned:true
partitionColumns:struct partition_columns { i32 date_key, string partition_id, string custom_partition_1}
totalNumberFiles:1
totalFileSize:247075687
maxFileSize:247075687
minFileSize:247075687
lastAccessTime:1561122938361
lastUpdateTime:1561071155639
```

The generic form of the command (taking out my specific values and putting in argument specifiers) looks like this:

```
show table extended like <your table name here> partition(<your partition spec here>);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do this:

```
DESC FORMATTED tablename PARTITION (yr_no='y2019');

OR

DESC EXTENDED tablename PARTITION (yr_no='y2019');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the location of the Hive partitions on HDFS by running any of the following Hive commands.

```
DESCRIBE FORMATTED tbl_name  PARTITION(dt=20131023);
SHOW TABLE EXTENDED LIKE tbl_name PARTITION(dt=20131023);
```

Alternatively, you can also get by running HDFS list command

```
hdfs dfs -ls <your Hive store location>/<tablename>
```

Link: [Hive show or list all partitions](https://sparkbyexamples.com/apache-hive/hive-show-all-table-partitions/)

Thanks,
NNK

Answer (score 0):

You can get this info via Hive Metastore Thrift protocol, e.g. with [hmsclient library](https://pypi.org/project/hmsclient/):

Hive cli:

```
hive> create table test_table_with_partitions(f1 string, f2 int) partitioned by (dt string);
OK
Time taken: 0.127 seconds

hive> alter table test_table_with_partitions add partition(dt=20210504) partition(dt=20210505);
OK
Time taken: 0.152 seconds
```

Python cli:

```py
>>> with client as c:
...     partition = c.get_partition_by_name(db_name='default', 
                                            tbl_name='test_table_with_partitions',
                                            part_name='dt=20210504')
... 
>>> partition.sd.location
'hdfs://hdfs.master.host:8020/user/hive/warehouse/test_table_with_partitions/dt=20210504'
```